# Add different attributes to derived classes #

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a base class named event and 2 subclasses named sendEvent and receiveEvent. You can see the code below:

```
namespace App
{
    public class Event
    {
        public Type type { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string correlator { get; set; }
        public string device1 { get; set; }
        public string device2 { get; set; }
        public string device3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string primaryid { get; set; }
        public string primary_correlator { get; set; }
        public string secondaryid { get; set; }
        public string secondary_correlator { get; set; }
        public string device4 { get; set; }
        public string device5 { get; set; }
    }

    class ReceiveEvent : Event
    {
       public ReceiveEvent()
        {
            this.type = Type.Recieve;
        }


    }
    class SendEvent : Event
    {
        public SendEvent()
        {
            this.type = Type.Send;
        }
    }


    public enum Type
    {
       Send,
        Receive
    }
}
```

I want that the sendEvent use first details while the receiveEvent use second details class. I couldn't figure out how can I make it possible. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I will redact my down vote when you edit your post and remove/edit/fix one of the two instances of the class `Details`

Comment: You can't have two classes with the same name, use `SendDetails` for one, and `ReceiveDetails` for the other, for example.

Comment: WHY exactly do you want two classes with the same name? If two objects have different purposes theay should go to distinct classes with a unique name.

Comment: Why not just put the detail properties you need directly on the classes which need them?  It seems like you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: Can I assign SendDetails and ReceiveDetails to Details later?

Comment: If there are common properties between the two classes then you can put them in a base abstract class called Details. See Rene's answer to fully answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base class `Details` and derive subclasses like `SendDetails` and `ReceiveDetails` from it:

```
namespace App
{
  public class Event
  {
      public Type type { get; set; }
      public Details details { get; set; }
  }

  public class Details
  {
      public string timestamp { get; set; }
      public string reference { get; set; }
  }
  public class SendDetails : Details
  {
      public string id { get; set; }
      public string correlator { get; set; }
      public string device1 { get; set; }
      public string device2 { get; set; }
      public string device3 { get; set; }
  }
  public class ReceiveDetails : Details
  {
      public string primaryid { get; set; }
      public string primary_correlator { get; set; }
      public string secondaryid { get; set; }
      public string secondary_correlator { get; set; }
      public string device4 { get; set; }
      public string device5 { get; set; }
  }

  class ReceiveEvent : Event
  {
    public ReceiveEvent()
    {
       this.type = Type.Recieve;
       this.Details = new ReceiveDetails();
    }
  }
  class SendEvent : Event
  {
     public SendEvent()
     {
        this.type = Type.Send;
        this.Details = new SendDetails();
     }
  }

  public enum Type
  {
     Send,
     Receive
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to separate the common fields into a base class and create subclasses:

```
public class Details
{
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
}

public class SendDetails : Details
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string correlator { get; set; }
    public string device1 { get; set; }
    public string device2 { get; set; }
    public string device3 { get; set; }
}

public class ReceiveDetails : Details
{
    public string primaryid { get; set; }
    public string primary_correlator { get; set; }
    public string secondaryid { get; set; }
    public string secondary_correlator { get; set; }
    public string device4 { get; set; }
    public string device5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your `Event` classes generic:

```
public class Event<TDetail> where TDetail : Details
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public TDetail details { get; set; }
}

public class ReceiveEvent : Event<ReceiveDetails>
{
   public ReceiveEvent()
    {
        this.type = Type.Recieve;
    }
}

public class SendEvent : Event<SendDetails>
{
    public SendEvent()
    {
        this.type = Type.Send;
    }
}
```

That way you can access `details` in a strongly-typed manner from either the base event class or the subclasses.

Comment: I was in the process of typing almost exactly the same thing,  +1 for beating me to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use single class Event you can use Generics:

```
public class Event<TDetails>
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public TDetails details { get; set; }
}

class SendEvent : Event<SendDetails>
{
    public SendEvent()
    {
        this.type = Type.Send;
    }
}
```